# Unable to use the volume flag with a windows container

Tags: docker-volume, docker-for-windows, docker

I am trying to map a host folder to the guest in the same way that is easily accomplished on linux/mac via `-v "$(pwd)":/code`. I can't come up with a simple example to make this work with Windows Containers.

```
docker build -t="webdav" .
docker run --rm -it -v C:\junk:C:\code --name webdav webdav powershell


C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container f0fa313478fddb73e34d47699de0fc3c2a3bdb202ddcfc2a124c5c8b7523ec09 encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call: The connection with the Virtual Machine hosting the container was closed. (0xc037010a).
```

I have tried countless other variations, and the accepted answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1051520/docker-windows-container-how-to-mount-a-host-folder-as-data-volume-on-windows) gives the same error.

The [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) seem to only refer to Docker Toolbox. The example only gives me `invalid bind mount spec`.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

RUN powershell -Command Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server

RUN powershell -Command mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code
ADD * /code/
```

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393

Version 17.03.1-ce-win5 (10743)
Channel: stable
b18e2a5

Disclaimer: I originally posted this on the [docker forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-use-the-volume-flag-with-a-windows-container/30575) but haven't had any responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:
Found it.  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume
"When using Windows-based containers, the destination of a volume inside the container must be one of: a non-existing or empty directory; or a drive other than C:"

Or here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only
"The following examples will fail when using Windows-based containers, as the destination of a volume or bind-mount inside the container must be one of: a non-existing or empty directory; or a drive other than C:. Further, the source of a bind mount must be a local directory, not a file."

It strikes me that these are non-obvious places to document this difference.  Where did you look for documentation of this issue?  I'll add this there :)

Is there a general need for a summary of differences between Linux and Windows?

OLD ANSWER (for context)
Here's a step-by-step guide on mounting volumes with the GUI:
https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c

From reading through some other forum posts it sounds like special characters in passwords may trip things up.

If you are still having issues here is one thread you could read through:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23992

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using windows containers. The shared drives tab in settings doesn't exist.

Comment: Fair point haha, my bad.  Can you try the Github thread suggestions and tell me what happens?

1. Reboot docker and try again.  If no luck...
2. Reset your machine to factory settings.  If no luck...
3. Ensure you have shared your drives in settings.
4. Ensure you have a password, and that the password does not have special characters

Do any of these resolve the issue?

Comment: Some more possible resources: [thread 1](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22981), [thread 2](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21535), [docker docs on data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#data-volumes), [docker machine docs](https://docs.docker.com/machine/), [doc on sharing drives](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives).  If none of these do it, Patrick made a [troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/troubleshooting)

Comment: The Github thread and the other threads in your 2nd post are for Docker Toolbox, not Windows Containers, but I tried changing the command to: `-v /c/junk:c/code`. I get this error:

`invalid volume specification: '\c\junk:c\code'.`

1) no dice
2) Haven't tried that yet, but this was a fresh install of Docker and Hyper-v and my first container attempt.
3) There are no sharing settings since it is not linux containers.
4) password has only alpha

I am looking at the troubleshooting guide. No errors in the logs.

Comment: I guess that answers where the moby doc repo generates to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if/where the moby repo docs publish to Docker docs, but [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30556) indicates that a volume cannot reference an existing folder in the container. In my example, I was first creating c:\code. If I change the command:

`docker run --rm -it -v C:\junk:C:\code2 --name webdav webdav powershell`

... it will create and mount c:\code2 in the container to point to c:\junk on the host.